# I want my calculator to restart until I press the 'q' letter

Tags: java

I wrote a simple calculator and I want that calculator to restart until I press the 'q' button. The problem is I can not get it to do that.

I tried some do/while loops, but I keep getting errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to my mini calculator program!");
            System.out.println("Please enter the numbers along operation (press q to exit):");
            int number1 = in.nextInt();
            char typeoftheoperation = in.next().charAt(0);
            int number2 = in.nextInt();
            String terminate = "";
            double result;
            switch (typeoftheoperation) {
                case ('+'):
                    result = number1 + number2;
                    System.out.println("The result is :" + result);
                    break;

                case '-':
                    result = number1 - number2;
                    System.out.println("The result is :" + result);
                    break;

                case '*':
                    result = number1 * number2;
                    System.out.println("The result is :" + result);
                    break;

                case '/':
                    result = number1 / number2;
                    System.out.println("The result is :" + result);
                    break;
                terminate = in.next();
            if (terminate.equals("q"))
                in.close();
            }



        }
    }
}
```

I want the calculator to just keep going until I decide to enter 'q', then it should stop.

Comment: Where does `option` come from ?

Comment: and big problem: you are using `nextInt()` to read first number - this will never accept the letter `q` - it probably would be better to read one line and check if it is a `q`; if not, parse it (`split()` and `Integer.parseInt()`). Or ask , after calculation, if user wants to continue or not

Comment: thank you for your answers i will work on it a bit then re post the new code

Comment: @Tom thank you very much i will sorry for that !

Comment: Whenever you are reading the number1 field, there you should also check if the user has entered “q” as an input first. If this check fails (which means the user has not entered “q”) then proceed with the existing calculator logic

Comment: This question here is quite similar to your case, maybe its answer will help you to find your solution: [I need to make Scanner check to see if input is "quit", and then if it's not, accept an integer](//stackoverflow.com/q/26066622)

Comment: @mettleap i  get what you mean but the first input is an integer if i put this condition its going to tell me you are inputing a string in an integer no ?

Comment: @Tom ill check that thank you

Comment: @Tom it did not answer my specific question

Comment: i brought few changes to it i hope im going the right way

Comment: its giving me unreachable code on the terminate = in.next();

Comment: By the way. Don't close what you didn't open. You are closing the sysin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a temporary solution to what you have asked.
You might also want to use try...catch... to solve the "inputmismatchexception".
But this will work for now.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Assignment2_3 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Welcome to my mini calculator program!");
                System.out.println("Please enter the numbers along operation (press q to exit):");
                int number1 = in.nextInt();
                char typeoftheoperation = in.next().charAt(0);
                int number2 = in.nextInt();
                String terminate = "";
                double result;
                switch (typeoftheoperation) {
                    case ('+'):
                        result = number1 + number2;
                        System.out.println("The result is :" + result);
                        break;

                    case '-':
                        result = number1 - number2;
                        System.out.println("The result is :" + result);
                        break;

                    case '*':
                        result = number1 * number2;
                        System.out.println("The result is :" + result);
                        break;

                    case '/':
                        result = number1 / number2;
                        System.out.println("The result is :" + result);
                        break;
                }
                terminate = in.next();
                if (terminate.equals("q")) {
                    in.close();
                    System.out.println("You turned off the calculator! See you again");
                    break;
                }



            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will also not work if you press 'q' at the very beginning. You have to perform operation and then only you can quit the calculator. If you want to do it other way around, it needs some work

Comment: thank you . you think it would be better to do it using arrays and strings only

Comment: it still gives me an error i think i should do it using strings and arrays

Comment: yes it would be better if you take an input using array of string and check out all input and act accordingly.